# Text Wrap (2 line text) is not working for <input type=“button”> in Opera

Tags: css, opera

I am trying to get button text in two lines, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav360/Yxqx2/

its working well in all the browsers except opera...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `button` element – simpler, with more consistent results:

```
<button id="btnQuoteNow" class="wrapText" type="button">Quote<br>Now</button>
```